# Do minor GC with G1GC result in global pause?

Tags: g1gc

We currently have JDK1.7 installed and configured to use G1GC. What i want to know is this.

Are stop the world pauses only a characteristic of Major GC? Or Minor GC has that issue as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question,

YES, minor GC activity causes a global pause.

http://blog.griddynamics.com/2011/06/understanding-gc-pauses-in-jvm-hotspots.html